# Vuejs - give me a way to select tab and refresh components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm having a problem now. When I select a tab, the input field in another component doesn't refresh causing the data to persist. I have to mention first that I'm storing data in vuex so I need a way to refresh the component so that it can be used. Thanks for everyone's answers.

```
<div class="card-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li
            v-for="item in tabselect"
            :key="item.id"
            class="nav-item"
            role="presentation"
          >
            <button
              :class="item.class"
              :id="item.id"
              data-bs-toggle="tab"
              :data-bs-target="item.target"
              type="button"
              role="tab"
              :aria-controls="item.control"
              :aria-selected="item.selected"
              @click="resetForm()"
            >
              {{ item.name }}
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabprovince">
          <div
            class="tab-pane fade show active"
            id="tablist1"
            role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="tablist1-tab"
          >
            <province />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabdistrict">
          <div
            class="tab-pane fade"
            id="tablist2"
            role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="tablist2-tab"
          >
            <district />
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
I'm still a beginner. If any of you have enough learning resources that can summarize and understand the work
```

Comment: What does your resetForm() do? Try Object.assign(state, getDefaultState()) to clear the state. Refer this: https://medium.com/@bluemagicy/reset-clear-vue-js-vuex-store-d91f4cbb007e

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-render/reload a component:

- call `this.$forceUpdate();` on the event onclick on your tab.

Or you can link a variable to your component by using the :key attribute.

```
<component :key="changingVariable" @click="reRenderComponent()"/>

export default () {
    data() {
        return {
          changingVariable: 0,
        }
      },

      methods: {
        reRenderComponent() {
          this.changingVariable += 1
        }
      }
    }
```

and everytime you click, the variable will be incremented and vuejs will re render the component linked to `changingVariable`.